# After the browser refreshes, the list of heroes doesn't appear

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-tour-of-heroes

I've been progressing well on the angular tutorial "tour of heroes" until my list of heroes failed to display while using angular's repetitive directive, *ngFor. Using npm -v6.4.1 and node -v8.12.0. The code is exact to what is in the tutorial.

I created a Hero class in its own file in the src/app folder and gave it id and name properties.

```
export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

This file called mock-heroes.ts in the src/app/ folder, Defines a HEROES constant as an array of ten heroes and export it.

```
import { Hero } from './hero';

export const HEROES: Hero[] = [
  {id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice'},
  {id: 12, name: 'Narco'},
  {id: 13, name: 'Bombasto'},
  {id: 14, name: 'Celeritas'},
  {id: 15, name: 'Magneta'},
  {id: 16, name: 'RubberMan'},
  {id: 17, name: 'Dynama'},
  {id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ'},
  {id: 19, name: 'Magma'},
  {id: 20, name: 'Tornado'},
];
```

I opened the HeroesComponent class file and imported the mock HEROES as shown below

```
import { HEROES } from '../mock-heroes';
```

In the same file (HeroesComponent class), I defined a component property called heroes to expose HEROES array for binding as shown below.

```
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {

heroes = HEROES;
```

I listed heroes with *ngFor as shown below in the heroes.component.html file by modifying the

tag.

```
<h2>My Heroes</h2>
<ul class = "heroes">
  <li *ngFor="let hero of heros">
    <span class = "badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the link to the tutorial on the angular page.https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2.
Remember, the list doesn't display in the browser and i don't get any errors in the console.
I'm using npm -v6.4.1 and node -v8.12.0

Comment: I'm new to angular, yet I've been loving it...so please help

Comment: Are you getting any error on the console?

Comment: I don't have enough reputations to edit the post but I think this tag for angularjs is wrong. It should be Angular or Angular6 instead.

Comment: @AIqbal No, I'm not getting any errors in the console

Comment: @holydragon hey, I've successfully updated the tags

Comment: It would be great if you could post the code here too

Comment: @user3284463 Alright, on it

Comment: @user3284463 Hey, I've included the code to my angular app

Comment: your variable is called heroes 
in for you are using heros
change this:
  `<li *ngFor="let hero of heroes">`

Comment: @lesiano Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have a variable typo `heros` in your loop statement.

It should be `heroes` instead:

```
<h2>My Heroes</h2>
<ul class = "heroes">
  <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
    <span class = "badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your .ts

```
heros = HEROES;
```

In your .html

```
<h2>My Heroes</h2>
<ul class = "heroes">
  <li *ngFor="let hero of heros">
    <span class = "badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```